# Migração de Alamofire 2 para Alamofire 4. Extra Argument in call (Request)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

Quando fazia os pedidos ao servidor usava o seguinte código

```
let URL = Foundation.URL(string: "http:....")!
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL)
mutableURLRequest.httpMethod = "POST"

let parameters = ["UserName": "Teste"]
  do{
    mutableURLRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
    }catch{}

mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

Alamofire.request("https").responseJSON{response in....}
```

Agora com a migração para o swift 4 já experimentei os códigos que estão no documento da biblioteca e já experimentei outras opções que vários utilizadores vão dando tanto aqui como em forums e normalmente tenho sempre o mesmo erro que é o seguinte "Extra argument in call"

Alguém com o mesmo problema e que tenho conseguido chegar á solução me pode ajudar?

Comment: Não seria `Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest).responseJSON{response in....}`?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver o problema do erro dos "Extra Argument" usando o código que demonstrei acima mas alterei o NSMutableURLRequest para URLRequest